AWS scheduler not stopping my EC2 instance
I created an AWS EventBridge with following configuration:
Target: Universal target
Service: Amazon EC2
API: StopInstances
Payload: { "InstanceIds": [ "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ] }

My EC2 instance did not stop at scheduled time. How can I debug this ? I don't see logs or anything. Should I enable dead letter queue to see what happens ?

Did you use the correct IAM Role with required permission?

Have you checked cloudtrail?
